# How do I prevent screen tearing in Windows 7 desktop with Aero disabled?

Tags: windows, aero, refresh-rate

After disabling all the Windows 7 visual enhancements, I began noticing some screen tearing while playing YouTube videos, dragging windows, etc.. It's very noticeable while looking at this:
 [Barcode Animation](http://www.amarasoftware.com/flash-animations/barcode.htm)
It looks like the fps exceeds the monitor's refresh rate capabilities (60Hz). Are there any hidden functions in the Windows desktop that can sync fps with monitor's refresh rate?

Comment: I hope you get an answer because I'm also using the classic mode and I get screen tearing on almost all video (including Youtube) and I have up-to-date hardware (i7 + high end nvidia card).